# Create Object async

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have a XAML application where I'm doing some time consuming things which I'd like to do asynchronously to make everything nicer.
At first I'm creating an instance of a class which connects to a webservice. It would be nice to do this first after the application is launched and display an information like "connecting to webservice..."
After the class has been instanced, I'm getting large amounts of data from the WebService which is then being bound and displayed in a `DataGrid`. This is the second task I want to run asynchronously while displaying a `ProgressBar`.
I understood the basics of async and await but I don't know how to declare the object in an async method after the application window is visible that I can further use it to get the data. Any help is very appreciated!

Here is some demo code which shows how my project currently looks.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public void Connect
    {
        //Connect to WebService
    }

    public List GetObjectIds
    {
        //get object IDs
    }

    public objType GetObjectById
    {
        //get complete Object
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent()

        ClassA hello = new ClassA();
        //This takes about 15 seconds. Shall be async
        hello.Connect();

        //List will be used as Source for DataGrid
        List<object> DataGridViewSource List<object>();

        //use the instance of hello to get some Data from the WebService. 
        List<int> objectIds = new List<int>();
        objectIds = hello.GetObjectIds("LDAPQuery");

        foreach (int id in objectIds)
        {
            //this takes about 10 minutes. Shall be async
            var tmpObj = hello.GetObjectById(id);
            DataGridViewSource.Add(tmpObj);
        }

        //do binding to DataGrid
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the for loop should run asynchronously?

Comment: Please be more specific than _"but I haven't had any luck implementing this"_. Please do provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably and clearly illustrates what you have tried so far and what that attempt does, along with a clear, detailed explanation of why and how that is different from what you want the code to do.

Comment: You are right. I have edited my question. My main problem is how and where to declare the object asynchronously after the application window is visible.

Comment: Note that WPF has async bindings (different than C#'s async/await) which might be more appropriate since you often want to have a property evaluated for a binding asynchronously and properties cannot use await. Otherwise I would recommend putting the async code into an event handler which can be async, such as the Loaded event rather than the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `await` asynchronous code in a constructor, but you can in an event. `Loaded`, for example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    // At design time (in your XAML), initialize to the "Loading..." state
    InitializeComponent()
}

private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ClassA hello = new ClassA();
    await hello.ConnectAsync();

    //List will be used as Source for DataGrid
    List<object> DataGridViewSource List<object>();

    //use the instance of hello to get some Data from the WebService. 
    List<int> objectIds = new List<int>();
    objectIds = hello.GetObjectIds("LDAPQuery");

    foreach (int id in objectIds)
    {
        var tmpObj = await hello.GetObjectByIdAsync(id);
        DataGridViewSource.Add(tmpObj);
    }

    //do binding to DataGrid
}
```

Comment: Well the asynchronous operation in that event handler is a fire and forget operation, which you could do just as well from the constructor if you wanted to by calling, and not waiting or `awaiting`, an `async` method.

Comment: @Servy: If you accept silent exception swallowing, yes. :)

Comment: You can explicitly handle the exceptions if you prefer, or simply call an `async void` method from the constructor, if you really want the same error handling semantics.